# Object keeps vibrating at pinned edge during cloth simulation

Tags: cloth-simulation

[image]

Hi, I'm entirely new to blender and have been following [a tutorial I found online](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7K5nHQbKg8s) for 3D modelling. To create a dress, I have created the object above and set it up with cloth physics. However it does not work as planned due to top of the dress getting distorted. The vibration/distortion around the waist happens to be were the object is pinned. I have made sure there is no clipping with the body already. But I cant seem to fix it. I would appreciate some help, thanks.

Comment: Try to increase the scales to huge values.

Comment: May I know what scales are you referring too?

Comment: Absolute object sizes in Blender units. Physics solver tends to have precision issues at very small scales

Comment: https://easyblend.org/html/editors/3dview/transform/basics/scale.html

Comment: Thank you both. I now better understand the limitations of blender and how to work around it.